# Runtime Error (Uninitialized Read) in Codeforces Contest

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I was trying to solve the [Prefix Suffix Palindrome](https://codeforces.com/contest/1326/problem/D2) question on Codeforces when I encountered the Undefined Read Error. Here is my [submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1326/submission/76739030)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define ll long long int 
#define MOD 998244353

using namespace std;

int KMP (string s) {
    int arr[s.length()];
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    arr[0] = 0;
    while( i < s.length()) {
        if(s[i] == s[j]) {
            arr[i] = j + 1;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            if( j != 0) {
                j = arr[j -1];
            }
            else arr[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return arr[s.length() - 1];
}

void solve() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
    while ( i <= j && s[i] == s[j] ) {

        if( i == j || i + 1 == j ) {
            cout << s << endl;
            return;
        }
        i++; j--;
    }
    int k = i;
    string newS = s.substr(i, s.size() - 2 * i);
    string rev = newS;
    reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());

    string pal1 = newS + '#' + rev;
    string pal2 = rev + '#' + newS;
    // cout << newS << " " << rev << " " << pal1 << " " << pal2 << endl;
    string res = "";
    int size1 = KMP(pal1),size2 = KMP(pal2);
    if( size1 > size2) {
        res += s.substr(0, k + size1) + s.substr(s.size() - i);
    }
    else {
        res += s.substr(0, k) + s.substr(s.size() - i - size2);
    }
    cout << res << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        solve();
    }
}
```

which gave the following issue

```
Diagnostics detected issues [cpp.g++17-drmemory]: ~~Dr.M~~ Dr. Memory version 1.11.0
~~Dr.M~~ Running "program.exe"
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x1059fe8c-0x1059fe90 4 byte(s)
~~Dr.M~~ # 0 solve               [K:\invoker-prod\work\codeforces6\2d955443cb64b59d0725278c4118bdb0\compile-dc6a4b92d96ace20e3fc7f428e5ccac3/p71.cpp:52]
~~Dr.M~~ # 1 main                [K:\invoker-prod\work\codeforces6\2d955443cb64b59d0725278c4118bdb0\compile-dc6a4b92d96ace20e3fc7f428e5ccac3/p71.cpp:66]
~~Dr.M~~ Note: @0:00:00.620 in thread 4944
~~Dr.M~~ Note: instruction: cmp    %eax 0xffffffe4(%ebp)
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ TERMINATING PROCESS after first error found
~~Dr.M~~ 
~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS FOUND:
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       1 unique,     1 total uninitialized access(es)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~       0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
~~Dr.M~~ ERRORS IGNORED:
~~Dr.M~~       2 potential error(s) (suspected false positives)
~~Dr.M~~          (details: K:\invoker-prod\work\codeforces6\e66acc517678db6ede3f663ff018663a\check-7d66d73ddd03e8e7418a8d6e48a639ee\run\DrMemory-program.exe.2504.000\potential_errors.txt)
~~Dr.M~~      11 unique,    11 total,  24568 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
~~Dr.M~~          (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
~~Dr.M~~ Details: K:\invoker-prod\work\codeforces6\e66acc517678db6ede3f663ff018663a\check-7d66d73ddd03e8e7418a8d6e48a639ee\run\DrMemory-program.exe.2504.000\results.txt
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000005
```

Line 52 is the one where I compare the two sizes after calling the KMP function.

```
if( size1 > size2) {
```

After reading about it I got to know that this error is caused when a variable has been allocated a memory but not assigned a value and it is used in an operation.
I tried assigning an integer to the variables which I thought would be the reason for this issue but no help either. Here are two more submissions to the same[76739874](https://codeforces.com/contest/1326/submission/76739874) [76740717](https://codeforces.com/contest/1326/submission/76740717)

Comment: Please paste your code here and also identify which line is giving this RE. Btw, did you try using a debugger?

Comment: So it's crashing on a substring operation. So presumably the error is the parameters to the substring call. Did you check that?

Comment: `I tried assigning an integer to the variables which I thought would be the reason for this issue but no help either` Making miscellaneous changes to your code without understanding the cause of the error is not the way to fix bugs.

Comment: @theWiseBro No I didn't try debugging it because I dont know in which test case it failed.

Comment: @SuvidSahay This is the huge problem with trying to learn coding from these sites. You are in the dark.

Comment: @SuvidSahay Oh, and the obligatory comment, `int arr[s.length()];` is not legal C++. It's an example of a variable length array (VLA). These are legal in C, but not in C++.

Comment: @john sorry about that but I just thought that the error is uninitialized read so maybe I need to initialise a value first. I was just checking whether if tha'ts the case or not.

Comment: Well the error seems like it's that, but that doesn't mean the read is from one of your variables. It could be from memory that's been allocated for one of your strings (for example).

Comment: @john I will take care about the array declaration next time. Sorry about that too.

Comment: @SuvidSahay In the line where it's crashing `res += s.substr(0, k + size1) + s.substr(s.size() - i);` the likely error is that `i > s.size()` so I would try and focus on that.

Comment: @SuvidSahay Although looking at the code further, I'm not sure how that is possible.

Comment: The maximum value I would return is s.szie()/2 so I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: @SuvidSahay Yes, I agree. OK, another theory, I see no guarantee that `arr[s.length() - 1]` will be initialised data. The preceding for loop doesn't not always assign to `arr[i]`

Comment: @john I am not incrementing the value the i unless I am assigning a value to `arr[i]`. So that won't be an issue either I suppose.

Comment: @SuvidSahay Not true `if( j != 0) {
                j = arr[j -1];
            }
            else arr[i] = 0;
            i++;` Perhaps you are missing some `{}` and meant to write `if( j != 0) {
                j = arr[j -1];
            }
            else { arr[i] = 0;
            i++; }`

Comment: I don't know how did I make such a stupid mistake. So sorry about that.

Comment: @john I am sorry for being this silly. Usually for mistakes like this I get a WA verdict. This was error was something new to me and I didn't think there could be a problem with my code. Sorry about this and thank you for pointing out my errors.